# SQL query to get an answer

Tags: sql

I've been given a database assignment which involves using queries for the first time to find specific results

[image: table diagram]

the question im up to states

> "Write an SQL statement to list all the properties that have been
>   viewed by one or more clients. More precisely, list the postcode,
>   propertyNo, the street of the property, last name of the staff
>   responsible for this property, client's last name, and the viewing
>   date. Order the output first by the postcode, then by the street
>   (screenshot required)."

the code I have:

```
SELECT   Viewing.propertyNo, PropertyForRent.street, PropertyForRent.postcode, Staff.lName
FROM Viewing 
  INNER JOIN PropertyForRent ON Viewing.propertyNo = PropertyForRent.propertyNo 
  INNER JOIN PrivateOwner ON PropertyForRent.ownerNo = PrivateOwner.ownerNo 
  INNER JOIN Staff ON PropertyForRent.staffNo = Staff.staffNo 
  INNER JOIN Client ON Viewing.clientNo = Client.clientNo
group by  Viewing.propertyNo, PropertyForRent.street, PropertyForRent.postcode, Staff.lName
having COUNT(viewing.propertyNo)>1
```

the results are for the most part correct except I haven't added client.lastname as it makes the results go to an empty table. am i using the right query to get the answer im looking for?

Comment: Please  [edit] your question title to something that actually describes a problem or question. Every single SQL query ever written is written to *get an answer* to something. Your title should be clear enough to be of use to a future reader who sees it in a list of search results while trying to find a problem solution. Your current one provides zero useful information.

Comment: Please tag your RDBMS as well as no two SQL dialects differ across vendors.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT pfr.PostCode
    ,vw.PropertyNo
    ,pfr.Street
    ,sf.LName
    ,ct.LName
    ,vw.ViewDate
FROM Viewing vw
    JOIN PropertyForRent pfr
        ON vw.PropertyNo = pfr.PropertyNo
    JOIN PrivateOwner po
        ON vw.OwnerNo = po.OwnerNo
    JOIN Staff sf
        ON pfr.StaffNo = sf.StaffNo
    JOIN Client ct
        ON vw.ClientNo = ct.ClientNo
ORDER BY pfr.PostCode
    ,pfr.Street
```

Had to re-read the question - could easily be mistaken for "more than one client." One or more clients means you'd include all viewings. Especially since they want you to include the client's info & a view date.

Remove your "HAVING" statement and add in the client's last name. I'd keep the group by or select distinct, so it'll only return unique records. You should be good!